# Count only lines with a few special words in special column indexes in a text file

Tags: python, biopython

There is a text file like the following in which I would like to count the number of lines with "HETATOM" at columns 1-6 (indexes 0:5), the "HOH" at columns 18-20 (indexes 17:19), and the "O" string at column 14 (index 13).

```
HETATM 2867  O   HOH A 402      -5.126  -2.185  31.480  1.00 16.92           O
HOH 2868  HETATM O   A 403      -6.727  -5.898  27.212  1.00 15.34           O
```

Because the code also counts the first line, I am receiving "2" instead of "1" as the output. Is there a way to modify the following code to count only lines with the words in the special column indexes in a text file?

```
pdb_text = open("c.txt","r")
hohs = ["HETATM", "HOH", "O"]
count_hoh=0
lines=pdb_text.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if all(hoh in line for hoh in hohs):
        count_hoh+=1
print(f'Number of water molecules: {count_hoh}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You can reference a substring by using the list slicing notation. You will probably be able to figure it out from my code:

```
lines = ["HETATM 2867  O   HOH A 402      -5.126  -2.185  31.480  1.00 16.92           O",
         "HOH 2868  HETATM O   A 403      -6.727  -5.898  27.212  1.00 15.34           O"
    ]

hohs = {"HETATM": 0, "HOH": 17, "O": 13}
hoh_count = 0
for line in lines:
    line_fits = True
    for literal, start_index in hohs.items():
        if line[start_index: start_index + len(literal)] != literal:
            line_fits = False
    if line_fits:
        hoh_count += 1

print(f'Number of water molecules: {hoh_count}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string slicing with [`for/else`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) like this:

```py
hohs = {
    "HETATM": [0, 5],
    "HOH": [17, 19],
    "O": [13, 13],
}
count_hoh = 0

with open ('c.txt' as f):
    for line in f.readlines():
        columns = line.split()
        for hoh, [start_column, end_column] in hohs.items():
            if hoh not in ' '.join(columns[start_coulmn:end_column+1]):
                break
        else:
            count_hoh += 1
```